# Create new column of data frame (vector type) with columns matching expression

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr, dplyr

Having a data frame with n columns, I'd like to create a new column that contains the vector (row wise) of some columns matching a regular expression. As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                 V1 = letters[1:4],
                 V2 = letters[2:5],
                 V3 = letters[3:6],
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

> print.data.frame(df)
  id V1 V2 V3
1  1  a  b  c
2  2  b  c  d
3  3  c  d  e
4  4  d  e  f
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(vectors = mapply(function(...) {c(...) %>% list},
                          select(., matches("V[0-9]"))))
```

To clarify it, with this example, the result would be the same as doing:

```
df %>%
  mutate(vectors = mapply(function(x, y, z) {c(x,y,z) %>% list},
                          x = V1,
                          y = V2,
                          z = V3))

  id V1 V2 V3 vectors
1  1  a  b  c a, b, c
2  2  b  c  d b, c, d
3  3  c  d  e c, d, e
4  4  d  e  f d, e, f
```

Is there maybe a solution with `tidyverse` / `purrr`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: the column "vectors" must be not a single string, but a vector. Please, see here below:

```
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id     : num  1 2 3 4
 $ V1     : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ V2     : chr  "b" "c" "d" "e"
 $ V3     : chr  "c" "d" "e" "f"
 $ vectors:List of 4
  ..$ a: chr  "a" "b" "c"
  ..$ b: chr  "b" "c" "d"
  ..$ c: chr  "c" "d" "e"
  ..$ d: chr  "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: I'm wondering if long-run the dplyr `pick()` function will help you (currently under development, see an example of the use [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4544#issuecomment-558591408) ).  Combined with `pmap()` for rowwise operations you could then do something like `mutate(df, vectors = pmap(pick(matches("V[0-9]")), list))`.

Comment: I guess right now you can use a combination of `select()` and `pmap()`.  Such as `df %>% mutate(., vectors = select(., matches("V[0-9]")) %>% pmap(list) )`

Comment: You gave me the clue :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @aosmith

This works:

```
df %>% mutate(vectors = select(., matches("V[0-9]")) %>% pmap(c)) %>% 
  mutate(vectors = lapply(vectors, function(x) unname(unlist(x))))
```